# Jenkins Plugin Build Error

Tags: jenkins

I wan't to modify the **Jenkins**-Plugin with the name **Deploy Plugin**. If I maven install the plugin the **InjectedTest** runs into a FileSystemException:

> C:\Users\froth\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson2805772493654455072test\secret.key:
>   Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem
>   anderen Prozess verwendet wird.

In English:

> C:\Users\froth\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson2805772493654455072test\secret.key: The process can not access the file because it is being used by
>   another process.

I think this is just a read/write problem of the VM or of Windows7. Does anybody know how to work arround this issue?

**PS**: *Here is the **StackTrace**:*

---

```
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running hudson.plugins.deploy.glassfish.GlassFish2xAdapterTest
Running hudson.plugins.deploy.glassfish.GlassFish3xAdapterTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.229 sec - in hudson.plugins.deploy.glassfish.GlassFish2xAdapterTest
Running hudson.plugins.deploy.glassfish.GlassFishAdapterTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.012 sec - in hudson.plugins.deploy.glassfish.GlassFishAdapterTest
Running hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargoTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.251 sec - in hudson.plugins.deploy.glassfish.GlassFish3xAdapterTest
Running hudson.plugins.deploy.tomcat.Tomcat7xAdapterTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec - in hudson.plugins.deploy.tomcat.Tomcat7xAdapterTest
Running InjectedTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.251 sec - in hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargoTest
Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 12.069 sec <<< FAILURE! - in InjectedTest
org.jvnet.hudson.test.JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyTestSuite(org.jvnet.hudson.test.junit.FailedTest)  Time elapsed: 0.005 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.io.IOException: Failed to clean up temp dirs
    at org.jvnet.hudson.test.TemporaryDirectoryAllocator.dispose(TemporaryDirectoryAllocator.java:86)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.test.TestEnvironment.dispose(TestEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.test.HudsonTestCase.tearDown(HudsonTestCase.java:414)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.test.JellyTestSuiteBuilder$JellyTestSuite.tearDown(JellyTestSuiteBuilder.java:138)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.test.junit.GroupedTest.run(GroupedTest.java:53)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\froth\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson2805772493654455072test\secret.key: Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird.
```

Comment: I exatly did the same things on my second pc with windows8. It worked fine...

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue on Windows 7 and opened https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21977 for this with some further analysis.

Still, as a temporary workaround you can disable the injected tests by adding the following to the pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>InjectedTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I'm stuck on this for a day now.. What was the real solution? i can't just disable the test...

Answer (score 0):

As a temporal solution also (from the 1st comment in the opened issue [link](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21977) in the previous answer) changing the version of the parent pom to 1.539 does resolve the issue with compiling; it worked perfectly with me without the need to skip the tests.